# Can't find the Xperia E dual 0.68 firmware source?

Tags: android, kernel, sony

I was looking on Sony's developer center for the kernel source of the Xperia E dual's 11.1.A.0.68 firmware, which, to my knowledge, is the latest ICS firmware for the device (all later ones were Jelly Bean). The only ICS firmware I can find there is 11.1.A.0.53, and that is a firmware I do not currently have access to. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you'll be able to find it. Sony isn't supporting development much on its low end devices. I tried finding Xperia M kernel but did not get anything from sony. Try using a kernel from xda dev or building your own kernel.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Actually I wanted to make a custom kernel for uploading on XDA; we don't have the ICS 0.53 firmware, and we don't have the kernel source of the 0.68 kernel.

Comment: i found sony's open source archive for xperia E dual though, [link](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/xperia-open-source-archives/open-source-archive-for-build-11-3-a-2-23/), hope it helps

Comment: That's for the Xperia E single, firmware 11.3.A.2.23; I already have that, 11.3.A.2.13, 11.3.A.0.47, and 11.3.A.2.1. I needed ICS, and that too 11.1.A.0.68.